# Почему не вызываются деструкторы обьектов при аппаратном исключении?

Tags: c++, windows, исключения

Есть вот такая программа, которая компилируется с разными моделями исключений под msvc x64.

```
#include <cstdio>

struct A
{
    A(int order) : m_order(order){}
    ~A(){printf("~A(%d)\n", m_order);}
    int m_order;
};

void foo(void)
{
    A a = 2;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 10 / i;
}

void foo1()
{
    A a = 1;
    foo();
}

void main()
{
    try
    {
        foo1();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }       
}
```

Когда используется опция `/EHa` то имеем вот такой вывод:

```
~A(2)
~A(1)
```

Когда используется опция `/EHsc` то имеем пустой вывод.

Возникает вопрос, почему не вызываются деструкторы обьектов? Насколько я понимаю компилятор реализует с++ исключение используя `windows` реализацию `seh`. Я думал что это как раз позволит корректно делать раскрутку стэка в любой модели исключений. Получается чтобы исключить утечки памяти и прочее мне всегда нужно использовать `/EHa` модель? документация от microsoft как раз утверждает что необходимо использовать по возможности `/EHsc` но как тогда это обеспечит корректную очистку ресурсов в случае аппаратного исключения?

Comment: Потому что **аппаратное** исключение само по себе не имеет никакого отношения к механизму исключений С++.

Comment: Про какие утечки памяти речь, если ваша программа все равно падает? Если вы ее не уроните (например выбросив самое обычное исключение, и поймав его), деструкторы будут вызываны независимо от настроек.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat как раз таки нет, в случае /EHa программа не упадет, она обработает исключения и завершится

Comment: @Harry но ведь исключения с++ внутри себя используют seh механику. почему тогда раскрутка стэка не работает для /EHsc?

Comment: @LmTinyToon *"в случае /EHa программа не упадет"* Я имел в виду только `/EHsc`. *"исключения с++ внутри себя используют seh механику"* Но это не единственная вещь, которая использует SEH. Деление на ноль использует SEH, но это не исключение С++. Ваш `catch` его по умолчанию не ловит (ловит только с `/EHa`).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat понятно что не ловит, но почему тогда и раскрутки стэка нет? я даже добавил внешний __try/__except, но под /EHsc по прежнему деструкторы не вызываются

Comment: А он и не должен раскручиваться в такой ситуации, вроде. Если вы обычное исключение выкинули и не поймали, то раскрутка [зависит от реализации](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate). А тут вообще не исключение...

Answer (score 2):

При обработке SEH исключений действия по финализации осуществляются в блоке `__finally`, а не при раскрутке стека. Причем они работают и в С коде, где исключений и раскрутки стека нет. Опция `/EHa` включает раскрутку стека при обработке SEH исключений по аналогии с семантикой С++ исключений. А использовать вам нужно всегда `/EHsc` и не смешивать С++ объекты и С++ исключения с SEH исключениями (возникновение которых при работе обычной С++ программы говорит о наличии в ней ошибки).